# Turn around order of PowerShell Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am writing a script at the moment in witch i would need to turn around the order of an array.
For example:

```
$a = @(1,2,3,4)

PS:\>$a
1
2
3
4
```

now i would like the array to be like this

```
PS:\>$a
4
3
2
1
```

Is that possible somehow?

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[array]::Reverse($a)`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Wow thats sweeeet! Thnx a lot!